# How to read DataPayloads in Push Notification in Kill/backgroud state

Tags: android, push-notification

I am trying to read data payloads when the android app is in kill state or background state. I have googled multiple place but nothing worked. I am able to receive and read the data payloads in foreground using this :

> remoteMessage.getData().get("message")

But I want to use this data when the application in the foreground onMessageReceived function. After multiple search I think that onMessageReceived is not been hit while the app in background. But is there anyway to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: How do you send push notifications? Can you share the code?

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase/38795553#38795553
P.S. you must send notifications not from firebase console and only with commands.